# 3D scan indoor locations

Tags: intel, realsense, slam, slam-algorithm

I know there are ways to 3d scan an object or a person using intel realsense, I wanted to ask if there are any ways to 3d scan and map an indoor location like for example a room?

Answer (score 0):

Problem of mapping the unknown environment is known as "[SLAM(Simultaneous localization and mapping)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping)".  you can search for libraries or applications using the keyword "SLAM".

[RTAB SLAM](http://introlab.github.io/rtabmap/)   is one of the publicly available application. You can use it with realsense directly to map the room.

---

Example result for RTAB SLAM

[image]